# Safely moving a hard disk between systems

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bitlocker

I have a system drive in a bitlocker and [WIP](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsitpro/2016/06/29/introducing-windows-information-protection/)-enabled environment.  I want to move the disk to another PC on the same domain, without data loss. The disk will be a data (non-system) disk on the new system.  In the past I've been burned by WIP: I can't decrypt WIP-protected documents on the new system.

I'm looking for a step-by-step for decrypting the drive, decrypting WIP-encrypted documents, removing any UEFI-related protections and setting up the disk on the destination machine.  Ideally I will also be able to re-encrypt the WIP documents on the destination.  Bitlocker will be re-enabled and the disk re-encrypted once it's installed.

PS: this post should be tagged 'wip' or 'windows-information-protection' but I don't have sufficient rep to create the tag.

Comment: Since this security is in place, ask for the assistance of IT which owns the domain.  If they say No, that's the answer.  That being said, there are easier ways to transfer files.  If those methods are locked down too, then ask for the assistance of IT which seems to have it thoroughly locked down.

Comment: I have admin rights on the machine, so I have a fair amount of latitude with respect to unlocking the data.  My goal is to transfer the hardware and selectively delete the data that I don't need.  I have a backup of the data but would prefer to move it in place so I don't need to re-copy it.